# How can I find the UUID and Batch size of my AWS Lambda

Tags: shell, jenkins, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I am trying to run a jenkins job which has shell script having AWS CLI commands,

I am trying to enable/disable Lambda Trigger(S3 Bucket) using cli commands in the script, steps taken-

1. These AWS CLI commands are run using an system user where its permissions are only-

   Read (3 of 41 actions)-->
   GetObject,
   GetObjectAcl,
   GetObjectVersion.

   Write (3 of 31 actions)-->
   DeleteObject,
   DeleteObjectVersion,
   PutObject.

   Permissions management (2 of 11 actions)-->
   PutObjectAcl,
   PutObjectVersionAcl.
2. Using aws lambda list-event-source-mappings --function-name MyFunction

   This is returning an empty array -->

   {
       "EventSourceMappings": []
   }
3. I have events/triggers(s3 buckets) configured for the lambda which are active and running

   If this command list-event-source-mappings returns the event values, I can enable/disable the "State" value in the resultset which should enable/disable the trigger in the AWS console.

I can use UUID and Batch size to enable/disable Trigger. Is there a way to know the UUID and Batch Size from the AWS console? Please help...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Using your own suggestion

`aws lambda list-event-source-mappings --function-name MyFunction`

works for me.

Given that the command is returning an empty array suggests that you have permissions to access the resource and that the resource exists. If either of those conditions were false, you would get an appropriate error message. My guess is that there are no source mappings for `MyFunction`. Try to create one and see if you get the same result when you list them.